# wxPython ontop of safari fullscreen

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I have code for a Frame, and it is always on top, but in macos when i full screen some apps like youtube in Safari it cannot overlay. But youtube fullscreened from firefox it does

Is there a way to get this to work on Safari as well? Ie: youtube, full screen the video player I would like the overlay to show.

Any help or advice, would be really useful. Thanks.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, w, h):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(parent, style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW)

        # self.SetTransparent(50)  # Set the window transparency (0-255)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)  # Set custom background style
        
        self.set_position(x, y, w, h)
        self.SetSize((200, 150))
        self.Show()

    def set_position(self, x, y, w, h):
        # self.SetSize((w, h))  # Set the window size
        self.SetPosition((x+w, y+h))  # Set the window position on the screen

    def on_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.GREEN, width=2))  # Set the pen color and width
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.GREEN, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_TRANSPARENT))  # Set the brush color and transparency

        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, self.GetSize()[0], self.GetSize()[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App()
        frame = Frame(None, 50,50,50,50)
        app.MainLoop()
```